# Problem with GY-521 module with chip labeled "MPU-6050A"

Tags: i2c, imu

I recieved this module. Which not woriking with my Arduino code (MPU-6050 example form Adafruit).
I test many things and find out that the problem happen with this version like 4 of them (my old module can work properly).

Mostly the problem appear as getting zero for all gyro and accel data. but get correctchip signature.

I try to dig down the problem root. Now I notice that chip label look suspiciousand i can't find datasheet of MPU-6050A. so what going on here? The chip is fake/defect or this is software problem?

[image]

Comment: I don't know if detecting a potential counterfeit from an unknown source is a reasonable question, however there are some potential issues with mixed 3.3V/5.0V systems.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany This question relate to the problem I've face. I hope that if defected chip is the answer, at least people will know it I save some time debuging for nothing as me.
MPU-6050 use 3.3V regulator also pullup to 3.3V as well. So we can connect with arduino safely. we can find a lot of tutorial about this. But this problem I never seen on internet. So I hoped it help people with same problem

Comment: Connecting it to a 5V MCU as are many, but not all Arduinos is indeed *safe* but it won't necessarily *work* without voltage translators. https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the HOW_AM_I log. I have one these  IC and it doesn't return the correct value. this is the answer
WhoAmI device reports as: 0x98 . Wrong response

Refer to this link
https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Register-Map1.pdf

page 45.
Sorry but this not an original IC's. I have the same problem
cheers